# SignalR WCF service to MVC5 Client. Is it possible?

Tags: wcf, signalr, asp.net-mvc-5

So I am familiar with SignalR in respect to Client/Server communication from a hub within an MVC Site project pushing to a javascript Client.  Its a very simplistic approach to Server to Client communication.

My issue is, I have a more complex architecture.  MVC5 UI that makes calls to WCF services where all the computing and business logic is occurring.

My question is, I have an MVC view that is a table of information. One column contains the # items within a box.  I want to update the view every time something is removed or added from the box.  However, adding and removing items are not done via the UI, they are done from an outside process calling into our WCF service.  We do some computation within the service and then update the count of items in the box and save it to the DB.  We would like, at the time of saving to the DB to also be able to Call the SignalR hub and have it notify all the clients that the count has increased which in turn will update the table on the view.  Can this be done? Can you make a call to a hub within a MVC application from a WCF service?

Comment: Your SignalR hub sits on the MVC application that updates its clients. From what I have understood after reading your description is that its WCF service that talks to the database. I think it should be possible to have a duplex WCF service that will update the MVC application when it updates/inserts the database. MVC then using SignalR hub can send message to the connected clients. This is just an idea.

Comment: Thats what im asking... can it be done and if so

Comment: Have you tried it? If / when i have some time I can post the code onto github but cant promise.

Answer (score 0):

> Can you make a call to a hub within a MVC application from a WCF
>   service?

Yes you can create a [Duplex Service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731064%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). In the callback operation (Duplex Service), the service can also call some function in the client. This function on the client is where you will make a call to your SignalR Hub method to notify your clients.

Have a look at the following samples:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dhananjaycoder/a-simple-duplex-service-in-wcf/

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752216(v=vs.110).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731184(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can,
when you have some change, call for hub, the hub broach to client and then client callback to refresh: 
client
 
        $(function () {

```
        var notifications = $.connection.pubsHub;

        notifications.client.alertms = function () {
            //if (ms === "pubs")
                getAllMessages()
        };
        // Start the connection.
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            //alert("connection started")               
            getAllMessages();
        }).fail(function (e) {
            alert(e);
        });
    });


    function getAllMessages() {

        $.post('@(Url.Action("GetMessages", "Home", null, Request.Url.Scheme))')
            .done(function (response) {
                $("#messagesTable").html(response)

            });
    };
</script>
```